# Can not override DynamoDB endpoint for Kinesis Consumer

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs, amazon-kinesis, localstack

Can not set up my local environment through aws-sdk, localstack and aws-kcl. After creating the consumer and trying to run it on my local environment I am getting an error that my credentials are incorrect. 
So Kinesis consumer always go to the real Amazon DynamoDB, and I can not point it to my localstack dynamodb. The question is: how can I point it to my local dynamodb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there are a few issues currently with connecting the multi lang daemon with the Kinesis Consumer Library, but I believe the settings you are looking for are buried within the kcl.properties, by adding these settings:

```
kinesisEndpoint = http://localhost:4568
dynamoDBEndpoint = http://localhost:4569
```

It should make the Multi Lang Daemon point to your local instances of kinesis and dynamo.

I've tried this multiple times with DotNet and it seems to be having issues further down the pipeline, but for now I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly the answer

Comment: But I started getting new error: Caused by: io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception: First received frame was not SETTINGS. Hex dump for first 5 bytes: 3c21444f43
 
I am searching through web all day but didn`t get success, do you know what it can be?

Comment: Yep - this is exactly what I get when I run my dot net KCL, I have no idea what is going wrong but trust me I'll let you know if I ever figure it out!

Comment: Spent one more day searching the solution but I'm starting to lose a hope that it's generally doable =(

Comment: So, resolved this issue by git checking out to the earlier release version. Hope it will help you.